# Built in Sign-In User Flow returns "your password is incorrect." Do built in policies work with custom sign-up policies?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have set up an Azure AD B2C application and created the necessary IdentityFramworks applications that are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=applications#register-identity-experience-framework-applications)
When Logging in using the Built in User Flow I receive "Your password is incorrect" but it is 100% the correct password.
I Created a Custom Sign-up Policy utilizing the starter pack.
Step 1:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName">
<DisplayName>User ID signup</DisplayName>
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
<Metadata>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">That Username is already taken, please chose another one.</Item>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">The Access Number or Email are incorrect.</Item>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
    <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
    <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
</Metadata>
<CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
</CryptographicKeys>
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />

</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_accessNumber" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_gender" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_dateOfBirth" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_error" PartnerClaimType="extension_error" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_message"  PartnerClaimType="extension_message"/>

    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />

</OutputClaims>
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="UsernameCheck"/>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="API-VerifyStep1"/>
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
```

Step 2:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonNameStep2">
<DisplayName>User ID signup</DisplayName>
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
<Metadata>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
    <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
    <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
</Metadata>
<CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
</CryptographicKeys>
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />

</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>

    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_city" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_address" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_province" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_postalCode" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_psc" Required="false"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_rsc" Required="false"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_altContact" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_altRelation" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_altConPhone" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_sciLevel" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_dateOfOnset" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUse" Required="true"/>


    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />

</OutputClaims>
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="signup-NonInteractive" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName" />
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
```

It seems that the account is found but the password is incorrect and I'm not sure why? Are built in policies incompatible if you have custom policies?

I also created a custom sign-in policy, but it leads to horrible formatting when the page is loaded, and it registers the username  field as input type="text" id="password" name="Password" placeholder="Username" value="" tabindex="1" Which is very confusing.

This is the sign-in policy

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username">
<DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
<Metadata>
    <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">False</Item>
</Metadata>
<IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>

    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
</OutputClaims>
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
```

And here is the login-NonInteractive Profile

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <Metadata>
      <Item Key="client_id">530a3472-...</Item>
        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">f134083a-...</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">We can't seem to find your account</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">Your password is incorrect</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfOldPasswordUsed">Looks like you used an old password</Item>

        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">username openid</Item>

        <!-- Policy Engine Clients -->
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="530a3472-..." />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="f134083a-..." />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Username}" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Password}"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

I know this post is long and I appreciate any input or help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your custom policy, a sign up where you collect the password on a different step than writing the user, will cause the account to be disabled. And then causes the error you are seeing at sign in.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where would I find that setting? I don't see it in the user's profile

Comment: Try powershell cmdlet “get-azureaduser”, or graph api to dump the user.

Comment: Also looking at your custom policy, a sign up where you collect the password on a different step than writing the user, will cause the account to be disabled.

Comment: To clean up the sign in page, use the normal combined sign in up step, but disable sign up using metadata item. See the reference doc for the self asserted technical profile.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I would have NEVER gotten that second part. I'll try that and update

Comment: Putting it all in to one step fixed the issue! Thank you!